# Axios : "Undefined" value is coming when fetch data from axios post reponse?

Tags: typescript, axios

I am using axios for API testing with Typescript and nodejs. I hit an end point and print the response like this:

```
   then((response: { data: any; status: any }) => {
   ids = response.data;
   console.log(ids);
```

**Response:**

```
[ 

{ Id: '36185-test-157485' },

  { Id: '36185-test-157485' },

  { Id: '36185-test-675946' },

  { Id: '36185-test-157485' },

  { Id: '36185-test-764344' } 

]
```

I am not able to get the first id from this response.
I tried with this:

```
console.log(ids.id)

console.log(ids.id[0])
```

I am new to axios. If anyone will suggest best practice, will be happy to use that also.

Complete code:

```
public listAllID's = async (idType: string, idOption: string) => {

    let ids:[
      {
        id: string [];
      }
    ];
    await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://test-abc.com/api/v1/Allids',
      data: {
        "type": idType,
        "include": idOption
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenId,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      json: true
    }).then((response: { data: any; status: any }) => {
     ids = response.data;
   console.log(ids);
      let statusCode = response.status;
      console.log(statusCode);
      expect(statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
    });
  }
}
```

This is called by this method:

```
Then(
  /^I list all ids of "([^"]*)" with other option  as "([^"]*)" from API$/, async (idType: string, idOption: string) => {
    await element.listAllIdsFromAPI(idType, idOption);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the first element's `Id` field in this way:

```
console.log(ids.id[0]) // wrong - the array does not have a property 'id'

console.log(ids[0].Id) // correct - get the first element of the list and access it's 'Id' prop
```